# Can loop device slots be reserved at boot for later use?

Tags: linux, chroot, loop-device

I'm working with a mounted root file system image in chroot that requires specific loop device numbers, and I need /dev/loop1 through /dev/loopN to be available for use after boot is completed, but snapd always snatches these slots up during boot. Is there a way to reserve these slots. Can I reserve these slots at boot time, i.e. for auto loop setup to start at loopN+1, so that loop1 through loopN are available to me after boot? Any other means of achieving the same end (such as masking loop devices in chroot) would also work.

Comment: Sure. You just have to get there before `snapd` does and `losetup` them to dummy files. Then, you unmap them and reconnect them. Knowing nothing about your system does not help though... Your particular boot sequence should allow for a initscript or something similar to be added and to run before snapd's does.

Comment: The **right** thing to do would be to modify your chrooted rootfs image so that it doesn't require hard-coded loop device numbers, just use the next available one (maybe save the loop number(s) to a file in /run or /var/run if it will be needed later).     Otherwise, make sure that your loopN reservation script runs **before** `snapd` - if you're using systemd, you could write a unit file that asserts `WantedBy=snapd.service` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you @EduardoTrápani and @cas. The `systemd` route sounds like the path of least resistance, since the rootfs image I'm working with is ro, signed, and the loop drives are hardcoded into `/sbin/init`, possibly other binaries. It would seem quite an undertaking to hunt them down, decompile them, find the loop references, and hexedit the changes into the image...

Comment: cool. when you figure out a viable method, please write it up as an answer and accept it.